# Error: SFDX Deploy source to org

Tags: developer

Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

Please help me.

Comment: All answers here are legit, I just wanted to mention that you might just simply have opened the wrong root folder, for example, I faced this issue by opening a repo from within Github Desktop in VSCode (Github Desktop gives you the option to open a repo in your default code editor). To fix it, I simply closed the folder in vscode and went to File->Open and just open the repo this way and everything is back to normal now, hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: This answer is really nice as well: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245143/getting-error-while-retrieving-source-from-salesforce-org-using-vs-code-and-sale

Answer (score 26):

If you are reaching this question in July of 2022, there is an issue with the most recent Salesforce CLI Integration Extension for VS Code on Windows.

To resolve, go to your extensions, go to Salesforce CLI Integration, click the drop-down next to Uninstall, and click "Install another version". Install the previous version (55.3.0)

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4261) to the known issue if you want to follow it for updates.

**Update 2022-07-11**:
As mentioned by @Swetha and @SFDC Dev 27 in comments, upgrading Salesforce CLI to v55.4.1 resolves this issue

Comment: I'm honestly grateful you're pointing this out, because I've suffered from this problem all day today and was already wondering. You could improve this answer significantly by referring to anything on Github or elsewhere that makes you think this is not just a problem of "our" configuration ;-)

Comment: As a fix, v55.4.1 of the Salesforce Extension for VS Code has been published. See the release notes here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/releases/tag/v55.4.1

Comment: decreasing the Salesforce Extension worked for me. And now I tested with the 55.4.1 and that also works. Thanks a LOT @EmilyHolden you saved a lot of hours for many of us

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error on retrieving the components from org. So i went to the package.xml file and right click > SFDX:Retreive Source in Manifest from org and it worked. Then you can try the SFDX: Deploy this source to Org.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem. I got the error when i right click and Deploy to Source Org.

Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

But i was able to deploy with the following command.

sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath .\force-app\main\default\classes\testFirstClass.cls --json --loglevel trace

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 1):

The folder in which you have/want to retrieve source code, you need to specify it in "`sfdx-project.json`" file. Also, this path should be relative to the directory of the project.

[image]

By default, all source code/metadata is stored in a folder called "`force-app`".

Currently, my `sfdx-project.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app", /* this is my relative path */
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0"
}
```

Just replace `force-app` with a relative path to your directory.

Comment: Can you please describe how can we give relative path considering your case?

Comment: @change_is_necessity I have added a comment "this is my relative path" in answer.

Comment: I have exactly the same settings but still I am getting the same error even on newly created project I am getting the same error

Comment: I never had this issue and I have like 10 SFDX projects. It just stopped working today. I was not abe to get it working yet, but I am wondering why it broke suddenly. Is it any VSC update?

Comment: Same issue, It suddenly stopped working...

Comment: @SFDCDev27 check the comments below question.

Comment: @Srujan check the comments below question

Comment: @Srujan create a new empty project, copy the package.xml file from there and replace the old package.xml where you are facing this issue,

Comment: Started today for me, after Windows update

Comment: Its the issue with Salesforce CLI, I I did sfdx update after couple of days and it resolved issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Swetha mentioned on her comment in the top answer, the extension has been fixed as of 2 days ago as part of v55.4.1 of the Salesforce Extension for VS Code

If you're still getting the error navigate to the Extensions button and click reload on one of the Salesforce extensions:

[See this image for instructions on reloading VS Code Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO0WB.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2023 w/this issue. I'm guessing there are a variety of ways to get stuck/blocked by this error but in case it helps anyone in a similar situation ...

### Issue:

One of my previous "SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org" calls pulled down a few files into /**profiles** and /**applications** folder. The existence of these files was producing the following errors:

> Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you
> tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's
> specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your
> "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or
> directory.

and

> Cannot create a new component with the namespace: standard. Only
> components in the same namespace as the organization can be created...

### Solution

Deleting the above-mentioned directories resolved the issue** and my SFDX: Deploy Source to Org (or command line equivalent) **FINALLY** started working again.

#### Notes:

- I realize I did not actually fix whatever the issue was - more like hacked my way out of it - maybe even just temporarily - *but at least it's gone now and I can get back to work.*
- I tried the downgrade/reload of the SFDX CLI extension - didn't change anything. I also tried deploying from the command line and from the VS Code command palette - both failed.
- Also I did not have any manifest/package XML file before all this mess - everything was working fine w/out it. Still don't have one. Project was created with the SFDX: Create new project / Standard command FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command Like Below:

**sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath '' --json --loglevel trace**

ex: sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath 'C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\TestProject\force-app\main\default\lwc\PatientDetails' --json --loglevel trace

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED This will solve for sure,**

to retrieve multiple Unlocked packages to local system we need to add multiple path locations to Sfdx.JSON file. this make DX to look at these paths and retriev/Deploye without any error.

Your **sfdx-project.json** should looks like this.

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
      { "path" : "force-app" ,"default": true }, 
      { "path" : "./ItemsToApprove" }
  ],
  "name": "Sandbox-Umesh",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0",
  "pushPackageDirectoriesSequentially": true
}
```

documentation given [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm)

**in my case
"path" : "./ItemsToApprove"  , where ItemsToApprove is unlocked Package that I want retrieve/Updae**

Let me know if this solves

I have answered here also : [Link to My Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245143/getting-error-while-retrieving-source-from-salesforce-org-using-vs-code-and-sale/395077#395077)

Answer (score -1):

Silly but in my case I was right clicking on the package.json on the root folder instead of manifest\package.xml

Answer (score -1):

I just modified "path", and it's worked in my case.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I also received the same error. I solved it by moving to file in force-app/main/default folder

Answer (score -1):

Clicking on manifest\package.xml worked for me I was incorrectly right-clicking on the manifest folder